# Tear in alocasia calodora

Tags: plant-health

There's been a slight tear on my indoor alocasia plant and I was wondering if it'll heal? Is there anything I could possibly do to help it?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you gave us a picture so we can understand the problem.

Comment: Just updated a photo of it!

Answer (score 7):

Plants deal with injury in a different way than mobile organisms.  Their mechanism is to let the cells surround the area with specialized wound tissue. Leaves in particular are disposable compared to roots and stems.

- the tear in the leaf will "heal" when dead cells wall off the wound area
- most indoor plants don't have enough light and too much water from their owners so you could see if you could provide more light

Answer (score 4):

The tear is likely to heal over as Kevinsky has said, but probably as a hole. As this will very slightly reduced the strength of the leaf, I'd try to let it dry, callous and heal over and then stick the two edges together with a slither of superglue! It was developed to stick skin together as small wounds, so this isn't a million miles away from that. It might be worth a go.